# Calculate expected correlation for a AR(2) process

Tags: statistics, correlation, time-series

Let $X_t = X_{t-1} + aX_{t-2} + e_t$ be a stationary AR(2) process. At $t = T$, what is the expected correlation between $X_{T+N}$ and $X_{T+N-1}$?

I know how to calculate $\gamma(1)$ but not conditional $\gamma(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for N=1 it is trivial that it is zero.  N=2. This becomes
$$X_{T+2}=X_{T+1}+aX_{T}+\varepsilon_{T}$$. So conditional on $X_{T}$ (subscripts are for $N$) covariance is

$$\gamma_{2}(1)=Var(X_{T+1}|X_{T})=Var(\varepsilon)$$.
Repeat for $N=3$
$$
X_{T+3}=X_{T+2}+aX_{T+1}+\varepsilon_{T+3}
$$
Compute the conditional covariance
$$
\gamma_{3}(1)=Var(X_{T+2}|X_{T})+a\gamma_{2}(1)
$$
Iterate forward and proceed similarly to compute the variance and arrive at an expression for the correlation coefficient

Comment: Hi, I tried to follow your hint and found that covariance terms appear in the expression when calculating variance which make it impossible to iterate forward. For example, $Var(X_{t+3}|X_t) = Var(X_{t+2}+bX_{t+1}+e_{t+3}|X_t)=Var(X_{t+2}|X_t)+b^2Var(X_{t+1}|X_t)+2bCov(X_{t+2},X_{t+1}|X_t)+\sigma^2$.  Also, I notice that we are not using stationarity here. Could you explain a little more about this problem? Thanks.